# If values in multiple columns match another dataframe, get sum based on range of dates pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, sum, conditional-statements

I have a two dfs:

`df1`:

```
    item_code   store_code  start_1      end_1
0   11185      01           2022-03-06   2022-03-08
1   11185      02           2022-03-26   2022-03-28
2   118113     01           2022-02-02   2022-02-04
3   118113     02           2022-04-29   2022-04-30
4   118113     02           2022-05-01   2022-05-02
5   000544     01           2022-04-15   2022-04-17
```

`df2`:

```
    item_code       store_code  date_code   sales_sum
0   11185            01         2022-03-06  1.5
1   11185            01         2022-03-07  1.0
2   11185            01         2022-03-08  1.0
4   11185            02         2022-03-25  1.5
5   11185            02         2022-03-26  1.5
6   11185            02         2022-03-27  2.0
7   11185            02         2022-03-28  2.0
8   118113           01         2022-02-02  2.0
9   118113           01         2022-02-03  2.0
10  118113           01         2022-02-04  2.0
11  118113           02         2022-02-05  3.0
12  118113           02         2022-04-29  3.0
13  118113           02         2022-04-30  3.0
14  118113           02         2022-05-01  5.0
15  118113           02         2022-05-02  5.0
16  000544           01         2022-04-16  7.0
```

What I'm trying to do, is to get `.sum()` of `sales_sum` if `item_code` and `store_code` is the same as in `df1`, within a range of dates `(start = start_1, end = end_1).`

Expected output should be:

```
    item_code   store_code  start_1      end_1        sales_sum
0   11185      01           2022-03-06   2022-03-08   3.5
1   11185      02           2022-03-26   2022-03-28   5.5
2   118113     01           2022-02-02   2022-02-04   6.0
3   118113     02           2022-04-29   2022-04-30   6.0
4   118113     02           2022-05-01   2022-05-02   10.0
5   000544     01           2022-04-15   2022-04-17   7.0
```

Nothing work from what I tryed to do, like `.sum()` with conditions `&` or creating multiple dfs in dictionary in order to apply for each chunk of `item_code` and `store_code` a range of dates.

Size of `df1`: 33667 rows, and
size of `df2`: 4408248 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` and `query`:

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, how='left', suffixes=('', '_'))
          .query('(start_1 <= date_code) & (date_code <= end_1)')
          .groupby(df1.columns.tolist(), as_index=False, sort=False)
          ['sales_sum'].sum())
print(out)

# Output
  item_code store_code     start_1       end_1  sales_sum
0     11185         01  2022-03-06  2022-03-08        3.5
1     11185         02  2022-03-26  2022-03-28        5.5
2    118113         01  2022-02-02  2022-02-04        6.0
3    118113         02  2022-04-29  2022-04-30        6.0
4    118113         02  2022-05-01  2022-05-02       10.0
5    000544         01  2022-04-15  2022-04-17        7.0
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe this will solve your problem.

Comment: Can you update your dataframes with such case?

Comment: I updated my answer. I changed `how='left'` and added `sort=False`. Can you check it please?